# Why the 'else' block in function works, meanwhile the 'if' block is True?

Tags: python, if-statement, return

```
def foo():
    if 1 > 0:
        print('Works first condition!')
    # This is a 'else' block which supposed not to be 
    # executed  cause of the above 'if' condition is True, but                                                          
    # despite the code executes both of them and return None!` 
    return print('Works second condition!')   

print(foo())
```

Output:

```
Works first condition!
Works second condition!
None
```

Comment: "This is a 'else' block" - no, it's not. Does it have an `else` in it?

Comment: There's not `else` block in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a closer look at your code:

```
def foo():
    if 1 > 0:
        print('Works first condition!')
    return print('Works second condition!')

print(foo())
```

In this code, you have defined a function foo(). The function contains an if statement:

```
if 1 > 0:
    print('Works first condition!')
```

Since 1 > 0 is always True, the code inside the if block will be executed, and it will print 'Works first condition!'.

Next, you have a return statement with a print() function inside it:

```
return print('Works second condition!')
```

The print() function will print 'Works second condition!', and then the return statement will return the value of print(), which is None.

So, when you call the foo() function with `print(foo())`, it will execute the function, print both messages, and then the return statement will return None, which is printed as well.

That's why you see the following output:

```
Works first condition!
Works second condition!
None
```

If you want to avoid printing None, you can remove the print() around the foo() function call like this:

```
foo()
```

This will only print:

```
Works first condition!
Works second condition!
```

Remember that in Python, every function implicitly returns None if there's no explicit return statement or if the return statement doesn't have a value.
So, in your case, the return print('Works second condition!') statement is equivalent to `return None`.

In addition, this code is not using the else condition properly.
The current code will always execute the if block because the condition 1 > 0 is always True. Consequently, the code inside the else block will never be reached.

If your intention was to use both the if and else blocks, they need to set a proper condition so that only one of the blocks will execute depending on the condition.

Here's an example of how the code could be modified to demonstrate the use of both blocks:

```
def foo(some_condition):
    if some_condition:
        print('Works first condition!')
    else:
        print('Works second condition!')

foo(some_condition=True)
foo(some_condition=False)
```

In this modified version, the function foo() takes a parameter some_condition. Depending on the value of some_condition, either the if block or the else block will execute. When calling the function with `some_condition=True`, it will print 'Works first condition!', and with `some_condition=False`, it will print 'Works second condition!'.

Comment: Thank you very much,I grasp why it returns None,but also there is cooments below my question like "there is no 'else' block in your code!!!" what that means?I considered that I can write 'else' block implictly after 'if ' and thats gonna work as 'else',does it?

Comment: Hello, in my last example i put how to use properly if-else statement

In Python, the if-else statement is used to make decisions based on conditions. If the condition provided after the if keyword evaluates to True, the code block under if is executed. If the condition is False, the code block under else (if present) is executed, providing an alternative path in the program's execution flow. The else block is optional, and if omitted, the program continues to the next line of code after the if statement.

Comment: got it and tnx again,I don't know why,but I assumed that there are cases when we can miss the 'else' key-word and it will work as suppossed,again tnx and can u suggest good articale regarding this topic?

Comment: if you want to have 2 (or more, with elif "else if") different results based on a condition you must use the if-else statement.

Article: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-if-else/

Comment: appreciate very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have an else statement, so the return (not the same as else) is run when the if finishes. Try with this:

```
    if 1 > 0:
        print('Works first condition!')
    else:    
        print('Works second condition!')
```

Also, if you have a print inside the function, use foo() instead of print(foo()). print(foo()) would be used this way:

```
def foo():
    if 1 > 0:
        return'Works first condition!'
    return 'Works second condition!'   

def main():
    print(foo())
```